# Import Novels/Non-Fiction from txt Files

Tags: python

I study literature and am trying to work out how I would go about importing a series of novels from .txt or other formats into python to play around with different word frequencies, similarities, etc. I hope to try and establish some quantitative ways to define a genre beyond just subject matter.

I particularly want to see if certain word strings, concepts, and locations occur in each of these novels. Something like this: (http://web.uvic.ca/~mvp1922/modmac/).  I would then like to focus in on one novel, using the past data as comparison and also analyzing it separately for character movement and interactions with other characters.

I am very sorry if this is vague, unclear, or just a stupid question. I am just starting out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

This is a really, really big topic.  If you're just getting started, I would recommend [this book](https://www.nltk.org/book/), which walks you through some of the basics of NLP using Python's nltk library.  (If you're already experienced with Python and just not NLP, some parts of the book will be a bit elementary.)  I've used this book in teaching university-level courses and had a good experience with it.

Once you've got the fundamentals under your belt, it sounds like you basically have a text classification (or possibly clustering) problem.  There are a lot of good tutorials out there on this topic, including many that use Python libraries, such as [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).  For more efficient Googling, other topics you'll want to explore are "bag of words" (analysis that ignores sentence structure, most likely the approach you'll start with) and "named-entity recognition" (if you want to identify characters, locations, etc.).

For future questions, the best way to get helpful answers on SO is to post specific examples of code that you're struggling with - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a good resource on how to do that.  Many users will avoid [open-ended questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) but jump all over puzzles with a clear, specific problem to solve.

Happy learning!